# Printing to invalid printer segmentation fault

Tags: windows, qt, printing

My program uses a `QPrintDialog` to select the printer in Windows. Once the printer is selected, I paint the canvas...

```
1 QPrintDialog printDialog(m_printer, this);
2 if (printDialog.exec() == QDialog::Accepted)
3 {
4    if(!m_printer || !m_printer->isValid())
     // also tried 
     // if(m_printer->printerState() == QPrinter::Error)
5    {
6        qDebug() << "printer error";
7        return;
8    }

9     QPainter painter;
10    if (! painter.begin(m_printer))             // program crashes here 
11    {
12       qDebug() << "failed to open printer";
13       return;
14    }

15    // do work
16    painter.end();
17 }
```

All is well, except if I select a non-existent printer on Windows. (Someone told me he used a non-existent network printer while testing the program, I used some "Sage PDF Converter" that seems to exist in printers list but probably not as working program). Any non-existing printer can be used to test.

Once the printer is selected, if the printer is "wrong" I get an error:
[image]

There is a segmentation fault that goes along with that image - and it happens on line 10 in the listing above.

(line 4 was my attempt to catch this error before it happens but... no luck).

How can I prevent my program from crashing, by determining if the selected printer is non-existing ?

Windows, Qt 4.7-5.5 (must work on Qt 4.7)

The stack trace: (using 5.5.1)

```
0   msgBeginFailed  qprintengine_win.cpp    98  0x16c0c929  
    actual line:  if (d.lpszOutput[0])
1   QWin32PrintEngine::begin    qprintengine_win.cpp    137 0x16c0cbca  
    actual line:  if (ok && StartDoc(d->hdc, &di) == SP_ERROR) {
             ->       qErrnoWarning(msgBeginFailed("StartDoc", di));
2   QPainter::begin qpainter.cpp    1808    0xc9f5f3    
    actual line:     bool begun = d->engine->begin(pd);
3   (the correspondent in my code of line 10 above)
```

In the above (on 0) `lpszOutput` shows 0 in locals and expressions.

I would not even want to get there though... I would like to be able to test that the printer is valid, before I attempt to paint on it.

The offending section - in Qt:

```
    DOCINFO di;
    memset(&di, 0, sizeof(DOCINFO));
    di.cbSize = sizeof(DOCINFO);
    if (d->docName.isEmpty())
->      di.lpszDocName = L"document1";
    else
        di.lpszDocName = reinterpret_cast<const wchar_t *>(d->docName.utf16());
    if (d->printToFile && !d->fileName.isEmpty())
        di.lpszOutput = reinterpret_cast<const wchar_t *>(d->fileName.utf16());
    if (d->printToFile)
        di.lpszOutput = d->fileName.isEmpty() ? L"FILE:" : reinterpret_cast<const wchar_t *>(d->fileName.utf16());
->  if (ok && StartDoc(d->hdc, &di) == SP_ERROR) {
  ->    qErrnoWarning(msgBeginFailed("StartDoc", di));
        ok = false;
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping though it with a debugger?

Comment: @Falmarri Of course - and that is why I can point out where the error is happening. I stepped through Qt code too -  error happens in qpainter.cpp `bool begun = d->engine->begin(pd);` - everything else (like setting the print engine) seems fine

Comment: It looks like a Qt bug. You'll have to patch your Qt sources to fix it.

Comment: @KubaOber - what should I do to fix it ? Is there anything I can test for ? since it is Windows, does the Windows API offer anything - and if so perhaps I can access it directly from my code somehow ?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "select a non existing-printer", by the way? Is there a list of printers somewhere? Populated how?

Comment: It's a crash in Qt code, so you should prepare a debug Qt build, then run your program under the debugger, select a "non-existent" printer, and see where it crashes. It does so most likely due to a null or dangling pointer dereference. Presumably the fix would be a one-liner.

Comment: @KubaOber that is exactly what I did, and posted the stack trace... I just don't know what I can do to fix it.

Comment: @peppe I explained exactly in my question. The "somewhere" and "populated how" is in the windows api.

Comment: @Thalia: not quite. I don't get what "non-existing printer" is (do you mean a virtual printer?), and how you're building that `m_printer` object.

Comment: @peppe: `QPrinter m_printer;` The rest is done by the print dialog. Please read a simple `QPrintDialog` sample. (http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qprintdialog.html - an example exists at the beginning)) Non-existing printer means exactly that. The list of printers on the system contains things that existed at some point and don't exist anymore. Like a network printer that got moved.

Comment: Re the stack trace: if `d` is null, then the object's state is invalid (is it `d.` or `d->`?). It `lpszoutput` is zero or dangling/uninitialized, then some prior API call has failed.

Comment: @KubaOber - it doesn't appear to be null... the first test (posted sequence of code in question) seems to be non-null object... Perhaps the StartDoc makes it null but that is not accessible.

Comment: Please make a self-contained testcase and file a bug report. Obviously a crash is not acceptable...